# How to make an Django Ajax Request with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am new to Ajax and want to make an Ajax Request to a view function in Django with jQuery, but I am stuck.

I started with a simple example to check if it works

```
var button = $('.any_button');
    $(button).click(function() {
        var button_value = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/url-path/to-my/view-function/",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { "button_value": button_value },
            beforeSend: function () {
                alert("Before Send")
            },
            success: function () {
                alert("Success");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error")

            }
        });

    });
```

I have inserted from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/

```
function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });
```

my view function:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def button_check(request):
    data = {"message": "Message"}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

My `url` path refers to `views.button_check`

I get the `beforeSend alert` and the `error alert`, but I expect the `success alert`

What did I miss? Unfortunately I am not able to go ahead.

Comment: Can you just type the url in a browser? If you open the dev tools (F12 in Chrome) in the network tab what is the error?

Comment: Yes, if I open the url in Browser I get the output {"message": "Message"}.

Comment: So is there any error in the dev tools network for xhr requests? What is the error? If it works in a browser then you should probably change POST to GET in your JavaScript code, typing an url in the browser makes a GET request.

Comment: Okay, now I have inserted `if request.method == "POST":`  and get a value error if I open the url in browser because there is an GET request as far as expected. If I click the Button that triggers the Ajax-Request I get the following Network error for xhr: `in Prohibited (403)
CSRF verification failed.  Request canceled.`  `Reason given for failure:
    CSRF token missing or incorrect.`

Comment: If I remove `beforeSend: function () {
                alert("Before Send")
            },` from the Ajax request I get the _success alert_ . I think it has overwritten the `beforeSend` from the csrf token function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in jquery try like this,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/button_check/",
    method: "POST",
    data: { "button_value": button_value },
    contentType: "application/json",
    beforeSend: function () {
        alert("Before Send")
    },
    success: function () {
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error")

    }
});
```

url should be,

```
url(r'button_check/', 'views.button_check'),
```

if your request is "POST" or specific try,

```
def button_check(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = {"message": "Message"}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: This works, but only if I remove the `beforeSend:` function, because the csrf token use the `beforeSend:` function.

Answer (score 1):

Your [ajax setup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) is overwritten by values you pass to jQuery.ajax:

```
  $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
      //this will never happen because it is overridden later
      alert("you will never see this.");
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/index.html",
    beforeSend: function () {
      console.log("another before send");
    },
  })
  .then(x => console.log("success:",x))
  .then(undefined,reject => console.error(reject));
```

This means you won't authenticate and get the csrf token missing.

As you told in comments; remove the boforesend in $.ajax

Comment: Thanks, this error I have recognized and already solved. Now I get the success alert.